# Oracle loop insert

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, insert, cursor

I'm having issues to perform one mass update in our Oracle DB.

I would like to do mass insert to mapping table which we can call **map**

There are other two tables from which I have to obtain the data  The first table is the **account** table from which I can select the desired accounts for inserting with this query:

```
select account_id
from account
where company_id in (
select company_id
from company
where company_name = 'string');
```

This query will select my all the accounts depending on the company name which I want to insert.

Next I have table which we can call **group** and in this table I have exact number of groups which I inserted, groups have UIDs so we have group_id 1 to 500.

Here is what i need to do: I need to insert into table map UID mappings between the accounts and groups.  There is no special order in which needs to be done

```
insert into map (account_id, group_id) 
  values (number,number);
```

But unfortunately I don't know how to do such mass insert with selects which are containing more then one result and also how to count the looping.

So my idea is do something like this:

```
insert into map (account_id, group_id) values ((select account_id
from account
where company_id in (
select company_id
from company
where company_name = 'string')),loop from 1 to 500);
```

With rule that `group_id` can be inserted with many `account_id`s but one `account_id` can be linked only to one group.

Of course this query will not work, I'm just trying to express what I want to do. Hope this make sense.

I since I know what exactly I want to insert where and I have all the counts I know that I have 500 `account_id`s and 50 `group_id`s.  Also they are in order meaning `account_id` 1 to 500 and `group_id` 1 to 500, so I think in this case it should be fairly easy to loop the insert somehow.

I hope I have made myself clear as much as possible.

Thank you for your answers and suggestions!

Comment: Instead of really long and confusing explanations you should post sample data with expected output. Create sample tables, add sample data to tables, type desired output etc... You can use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ or simply type it all in your post. Use ctrl+k to add code to your post.

Comment: what is the point of the map table in the future? This is rather unclear how and why you want to join groups and accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This will insert every combination of account id and group id:

```
INSERT INTO map(account_id, group_id)
SELECT a.id, g.id
FROM account a, group g
WHERE a.company_id IN ( select company_id 
                        from company 
                        where company_name = 'string');
```

EDIT: If I understood you comment correctly, you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO map(account_id, group_id)
SELECT a.id, g.id
FROM account a, group g
WHERE a.company_id IN ( SELECT company_id 
                        FROM company 
                        WHERE company_name = 'string')
AND 1000 <= a.id AND a.id <= 1500
AND g.id = a.id + 1000;
```

Which will connect account 1000 with group 2000, account 1001 with group 2001, and so on. A bit unnecessary to join the group now, but it will make sure a row with the expected group id exists (and skip it if it doesn't).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately i was maybe so accurate but i want to insert only some combinations of account_id and group_id i have a hundreds of thousands of both but i want to insert just some of them to the mapping table. So i can identify/select all the account_id's using the select from the company table or use some loop since i know the account_id's which i want to insert are for instance from 1000-1500 and i also know that the groups_id's are from 2000-2500. Home it make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work. It uses the `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax (see an example [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php)) to insert multiple rows from a query.

To loop, cross join the results with this query, which will give you a table of 500 rows with sequential numbers.

```
select LEVEL as group_id from dual connect by LEVEL <= 500
```

Here's the final answer. It's untested so you may need to fix and tweak, but that's the general approach:

```
insert into map (account_id, group_id)
  select account_id, group_id
    from account
    where company_id in (select company_id 
                         from company 
                         where company_name = 'string')
  cross join (select LEVEL as group_id
              from dual 
              connect by LEVEL <= 500)
```

**Addition** - OP asked how a query including groups 1,000 through 1,500 (instead of 1 through 500) would work...

The `CONNECT BY LEVEL` always has to start at 1, so you'll need to `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1500` in an inner query and filter out 1 through 999 with an outer WHERE clause. Here's an example; the differences are all in the cross-joined query:

```
insert into map (account_id, group_id)
  select account_id, group_id
    from account
    where company_id in (select company_id 
                         from company 
                         where company_name = 'string')
  cross join (
     select group_id from (
       select LEVEL as group_id
         from dual
         connect by LEVEL <= 1500)
     where group_id >= 1000)
```

I don't have Oracle within reach at the moment so this is untested like my prior answer.

Also note: going up to 1,500 like this is no problem, but at some point you'll notice a slowdown. I don't know if it will be at 10,000 or 100,000 or a million, but sooner or later you could hit a wall.

Comment: This looks like something what i can use! At least something what i can use in the future, I'm not so strong with SQL so i was workingaround the insert from select with generating a huge lists of single inserts with AWK :D Actually already written few shell generators for it :D but all the time i felt its not the best solution.

Comment: Only one additional question to the level solution if the group_id not begins by 1 but for instance 1000 and ends by 1500, how to apply this solution? Sorry for not using the exact numbers, i was trying to keep it more theoretical for more possible solutions.

Comment: @Fil - sorry, just saw your "1000 to 1500" question today because I had a long-overdue weekend offline :) I added that as an edit to my original answer. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question:

```
INSERT INTO map(account_id, group_id)
SELECT a.id, g.id
  FROM account a
 INNER JOIN company c
    ON a.company_id = c.company_id
   AND c.company_name = 'string'
 CROSS JOIN group g
```

My pet peeve, quit controlling the SQL! You don't have to use `IN`.